# How to make SFINAE work to choose template method inherited through multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, sfinae

Trying to implement the observer pattern, I would like that subject and observer represent all possible type of events (avoid duplicated code).
I would like also to allow classes to inherit multiples times from subject to be observable by multiple events, through multiple inheritance. One solution is to make register/notify/etc... methods template, to make it "like" different name but with same code and to disambiguiate the call without having to make a wrapper function.

What I would like to have:

```
object obj;
obj.registerEvent<Event1>(observer1);
obj.registerEvent<Event2>(observer2);
obj.registerEvent<Event3>(observer3);
...
```

Actual code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <set>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template<typename Event>
class Observer
{
public:

protected:
    Observer() = default;

public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

template<typename Event>
class Subject
{
private:
    std::set<Observer<Event>*> m_observers;

protected:
    Subject() = default;

public:

#define same_template \
    template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Event>::value>::type>

    same_template
    void registerObserver(Observer<Event>* observer, Event* = 0)
    {
        m_observers.insert(observer);
    }

    same_template
    void removeObserver(Observer<Event>* observer, Event* = 0)
    {
        m_observers.erase(observer);
    }

    same_template
    void notifyObservers()
    {
        std::for_each(m_observers.begin(), m_observers.end(), [] (Observer<Event> *observer) {
            observer->update();
        });
    }
};

TEST(PatternObserverTest, CompilationTest)
{

    struct Move {};
    struct Jump {};
    struct Player : Subject<Move>, Subject<Jump> {

        void move()
        {
            notifyObservers<Move>(); // ERROR: member found in multiple bases classes of different types
        }

        void jump()
        {
            notifyObservers<Jump>(); // ERROR: member found in multiple bases classes of different types
        }
    };

    struct Level : Observer<Move>, Observer<Jump> {

        void update()
        {

        }
    };

    Player player;
    Level level;

    player.template registerObserver<Move>(&level); // ERROR: member found in multiple bases classes of different types
}
```

I even tried to add one foo parameter (Event*) if ever it would break the ODR.

The problem is, to choose the good method override. It look like SFINAE don't work over multiple inheritance. How can I make it work?

My guess:
I thought the compiler makes a set of all possible methods and then, eliminate the wrong candidates by instanciation, and then if there is exactly 1 remaining method, call it, or throw an error.
It look like the compiler does it: it make a set of possible methods and because there is more than one candidate, deduce immedialty that the call is amibiguous because the scopes are differents before even instanciating the methods, by looking at function name only and not function signature.

I know a can make a workaround with a common superclass, and casting (method 2) or generating unique id per type (method 3), but I would like to stuck to C++ that can't compile and crash because of syntax error.

Comment: Notice that `registerObserver` and `removeObserver` doesn't need to be template (`T` is unused, and argument `Observer<Event>*` would allow to differentiate overloads)

Comment: I made it template for if, for exemple, Level inherit simultaneously from Observer<Jump> and Observer<Move> (with actual code)

Comment: Indeed, but you can then use syntax `player.Subject<Move>::registerObserver(&level)` to desambiguate.

Answer (score 0):

Functions must be in the same scope in order to be subject to overload resolution, and can be introduced to the `Player` scope with a `using` declaration:

```
struct Player : Subject<Move>, Subject<Jump>
{
    using Subject<Move>::notifyObservers;
    using Subject<Jump>::notifyObservers;
    using Subject<Move>::registerObserver;
    using Subject<Jump>::registerObserver;

    void move()
    {
        notifyObservers<Move>();
    }

    void jump()
    {
        notifyObservers<Jump>();
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KjXceqfyGhUqEdHc)

Comment: Yes. As a side note, I don't think you need SINFAE, as a simple overload resolution should do the trick ([`demo 2`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oL5QPHj76320M6J1))

Comment: Ok, thank you. The SFINAE was if an Observer inherited from multiple Observer. i. e. `struct Level : Observer<Move>, Observer<Jump>;`. Finally adding also an event parameter make it also more simpler (`notifyObservers(Jump{})`) and can dispatch more information.

Comment: I deleted the comment about `Subject<Move>::notifyObserver` syntax, because this will not work for `registerObserver`

Comment: (unless you intend to write `player.Subject<Move>::registerObserver(...)` )